# JAVA SVN USERNAME

Tags: svn

i need to change the username of my svn, because whenever i commit a change it appear that the change is made by a another person,(He use my system earlier).

Comment: This is not a programming question.  I think 'serverFault' would be a better place to ask this.  (And I'm going to get rid of the Java tag.  The Q has nothing to do with Java.)

Comment: You need to change your default SVN user for the code-base. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624/how-do-i-change-the-default-author-for-accessing-a-local-svn-repository

Comment: Which SVN client are you using?